# Bounty expiration lacks a functionality

Tags: bug, bounty

[This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106122/iphone-5-6-ram-security) question was set on bounty, but never replied to.
In my inbox I received this message now that the bounty is expiring
"...you must award it to an answer within 24 hours."

This message doesn't seem to consider the scenario.
Not a big nuisance, just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: It seems this was considered, and explicitly accepted: http://security.stackexchange.com/help/bounty